# Convert CSV / GeoJson / Shape file to DXF file in Php

Tags: php, geojson, spatial, dxf

Is there a way to convert spatial data to a dxf file in php?

Something like https://geoconverter.hsr.ch/

Want to export the the data from the database in the form of dxf file.
Is it possible to post the data to any web service to convert it to dxf?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [DXF-Creator-for-PHP](https://github.com/active-programming/DXF-Creator-for-PHP)

Answer (score 0):

[GDAL](http://gdal.org) can read virtually any spatial data format you could imagine, including CSV, GeoJSON and shapefiles, and can translate between then using the `ogr2ogr` command line tool.

[GDAL's support for PHP is doubtful](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/GdalOgrInPhp), so you might have to shell out to `ogr2ogr` from your PHP code using the [`system`](http://php.net/system) function.